# On the integral of Frobenius norm of Jacobian

Tags: differential-geometry, jacobian

Let $g : S \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be injective and smooth where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $k$-dim regular smooth compact manifold with $d \geq k$.

I'de considering the term
$$
A = \int_S \lVert J_g(x) \rVert_F \, dx
$$
where $J_g$ is Jacobian matrix of $g$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert_F$ is Frobenius norm.

If $S$ is an one-dimensional interval on $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is a the length of the curve given by $g(S)$.

I have following questions:

1. What would be a physical meaning of $A$?
2. Does increasing the $k$-dimensional area of $g(S)$ increases $A$, and vice versa?
3. If 2 is true, how to simply prove?

Hopefully my question is not so stupid one.

Comment: For $k > 1$ I have a hard time imagining a physical meaning of just the Frobenius norm itself, let alone this integral. It's just the special case for 1D where it happens to coincide with $L_2$. Does there need to be a physical meaning?

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Not have to, but it would be much better for me if it has. The term arises in my experimental study. 

I believe the norm of Jacobian measures the rate of change in $g$ with respect to the chagne of its input with complete disregard of its direction. And the inegral is just summing up over all $x$'s.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman But my understanding is too naive. I thought the term might have connection to some quantities in physics or differential geometry.

Comment: What is $dx$ in the integral?

Comment: @Deane Just conventional $dx$ in Riemann or Lebesgue integral. I assume $S$ is just a simple connected set that we can imagine (nothing complicated nor general). It is the support of the Frobenius norm of Jacobian.

Comment: Sorry. Still confused. Could you give an explicit example of an $S$ you have in mind? Since you appear to be interested only in the local situation, perhaps it would be better to just let $S$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: @Deane Thanks for interaction! Just a simple (closed or open) unit cube would definitely serve for my purpose. And yes, local consideration is enough for my case as long as $S$ is bounded.

The term arises in a computational simulation. In fact, anything reasonable can be assumed to make the question easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\|J_g(x)\|^2$ is often called the energy density at $x$ of the map $g$. Here, the constant map is viewed as having the least density, so the energy can be viewed as measuring the energy due to stretching $S$. The integral of the energy density is therefore called the total energy. Given some additional constraints on the map $g$ (so, for example, it isn't allowed to be the constant map), it is natural to ask when $g$ is energy-minimizing. Energy-minimizing maps are known as harmonic maps.

You can also treat $\|J_g\|^p$, including $p = 1$, as a type of energy density and study so-called $p$-harmonic maps. This is done less, simply because $p=2$ is the case that arises more naturally in physics and is also much easier to study mathematically.

The area of $g(S)$ is given by the integral of $\det J_g$. Since it's possible to increase $\det J_g$ but not $\|J_g\|$ and vice versa, there's no reason why the change in area should force a change in the energy or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Deane. This is exactly what I wanted. I have few more questions though. Please let me ask you kindly if okay.

Comment: 1. I tried to google out the energy density. Is it the energy desity arising in the electric field of physics?

Comment: 2. I believe this is quite a technical stuff and not really related to the original question, but in my case, $d$ can be actually greater than $k$, and thus $J_g$ is not a square matrix, not defining its determinant. 
I am wondering if (even in the case where there is no coordinate transformation that can put $g(S)$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$),
there would be a simple trick to use $\det J_g$ to compute the area of $g(S)$.
(I never studied differential geometry. I m just wondering if I can find an answer to this in introductory textbooks)

Comment: I probably shouldn’t have used the word “physics”, since I’m a mathematician. In classical physics, harmonic functions and fields arise naturally, for example in electromagnetism. Harmonic maps, as far as I know, don’t, except possibly in solid mechanics. I suggest googling harmonic maps and see if anybody cites a physics book or paper.

Comment: If $k < d$ and you want to compute the area (k-dimensional volume) of $g(S)$, this is indeed explained in many differential geometry textbooks. You can in fact define the determinant of the Jacobian, even if it is not square and integrate it to get the volume.

Comment: Thank you very much Deane for your immense help!